# Blazor WASM app with both jwt Token and Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor web assembaly app.
I am trying to let the user either log in with their azure ad credentials or with their credentials stored in a DB.

I can get them both to work but not at the same time. I need to impliment a custom authentication state provider to save the authentiction credentials for the JWT so they are authorized on each page/api.

having this custom authentication state provider cases a conflict when using `

```
        builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
       {

           builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
            //   options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");

            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://2913a4cb-b93e-4107-bd31-1f963e967f30/API.Access");
           options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";
           options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
           options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
       }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>();`
```

to set up the azure ad loggin in.

how do I enable it so the user can log in with either and be authorised to use the APIs/view the pages

Comment: What version of .net is this? There is tooling now to configure Azure AD instead of signing into the portal.

Comment: @BrianParker .Net 5.0 what tooling is that? I have not seen any tutorials that show a different way of using azure ad

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_create

Comment: Thanks @BrianParker that looks like it is more to set it up, I have azure login working in the blazor app. the problem is when I try and add JWT custom auth state in. It conflicts with the azure side of things

Comment: @MartinDempsey
have the exactly same issue right now. Any fixes ?